# Как узнать id только что вставленной строки на golang+Mysql либо golang+PostgreSQL?

Tags: mysql, postgresql, golang, mariadb

Как узнать id только что вставленной строки на golang+Mysql либо golang+PostgreSQL?
Нужно выполнить insert запрос и тут-же узнать какой id новой строки, что б дальше работать.

Comment: [mysql](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28776926/4827341) (не уверен в работоспособности) и [postgresql](https://godoc.org/github.com/lib/pq#hdr-Queries)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Пример для Postgres (ключевой момент -- `RETURNING id` в запросе `INSERT`):

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "database/sql"
    _ "github.com/lib/pq"
)

func main() {
    db, err := sql.Open(
        "postgres",
        "user=test password=test dbname=test sslmode=disable")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("error: %v\n", err)
    }

    stmt, err := db.Prepare("INSERT INTO test(value) VALUES($1) RETURNING id")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("error: %v\n", err)
    }

    var id int
    err = stmt.QueryRow("value to insert").Scan(&id)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("error: %v\n", err)
    }

    fmt.Printf("inserted object's ID: %d\n", id)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
stmt, _ := connection.Prepare("INSERT ....")
res, _ := stmt.Exec()
id, err := res.LastInsertId()
```

Вот [здесь](http://simpledev.su/2017/10/19/golang-mysql-vstvka-zapisi-v-bazu-dannykh/) болле полный пример как сделать INSERT в MySQL и получить id записи